# laravel cashier subscription cancel on trial period

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, cancellation

I am using laravel cashier for stripe integration. I am able to cancel if he is paid customer. If customer is under trial period i am unable to cancel subscription of user. How to cancel subscription even user is on trial.

> $subDomainAccnt->subscription('main')->cancel();

Answer (score 1):

You are canceling it right but

> When a subscription is cancelled via `cancel()`, Cashier will automatically set the ends_at column in your database. This column is used to know when the subscribed method should begin returning  false. For example, if a customer cancels a subscription on March 1st, but the subscription was not scheduled to end until March 5th, the subscribed method will continue to return  true until March 5th

When you should be using another method to cancel immediatelly

> If you wish to cancel a subscription immediately, call the `cancelNow` method on the user's subscription

Quotes taken from `Subscription cancelling` from [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/billing#cancelling-subscriptions)